# Magento 1.x: Copy System Configuration (core_config_data) values from a website to another

Tags: magento-1.9, system-configuration, multi-website

I have a magento website having three websites: `web1`, `web2` & `web3`

I need to set all system configuration values from `web2` to another new website `web3` **but** `web1` should not be affected.

If any one have easiest possible way to do this. Please share

Answer (score 1):

First run:
**`select * from core_config_data where scope='stores' and scope_id=<id_of_web2>;`**

By this you will get all configuration rows for web2.

Hold result in a php variable, say **`$result`**. Now use:

```
foreach($result as $value){

// Now check any configuration path exists for web3, if yes, then update
// if no, then use value of web2's configuration and insert a new row for path with value for web3

}
```